# include directive paths in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to include `topnav.blade.php` file in `master.blade.php` in the IDE.

[This is shows all the directories in the view folder of my laravel application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1SXw.jpg)

```
error message is 
[debug error
][1]
```

Below is the path that I am using in my application and I am still struggling to find why it's not working.

```
@include('.. /_includes/nav/topnavbar')
```

I'd be grateful if anyone could shade some light on this.
Thank you.

Comment: when using blade syntax like`@extends`, `@include`, `@yield`, and `@section`, it should be `@include('directory.inner-directory.bladename')` where `directory` is under `response/views`. `directory, inner-directory, bladename` should be separated by dot 「.」

Comment: In your case, it should be `@include('_includes.nav.topnavbar')`. You don't need to do `../` to go back from a previous directory since blade will always look from `response/views`

Comment: It should be ```@include('_includes.nav.topnav')```, But I wonder why you use **topnavbar**, but in the image, the file is **topnav**, not **topnavbar**.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `@include('_includes.nav.topnavbar')`

Official documentation - https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#including-subviews

Comment: but I need to go to the parent directory first and then go into the _inlcudes directory but your answer would work if the _includes directory and and the master files are at the same level.

Comment: Have you tried my code?

Comment: Thank you Mr. Dishan. I found the error. It was a typo. I have included in the path "topnavbar" as the blade name but it has to be "topnav" only.